# Copy and Edit HTML in Memory

Tags: java, html, io

I'd like to read in a HTML file I've specified, and instead of editing and saving the file, I'd like to use a `StringBuilder` to modify that data and save it in memory so that I may save it elsewhere or do various tasks to it.

Assuming I want to edit a similarly formatted HTML file:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <p>Data</p>
          <p>More data</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to be able to input information after the last set of data "More data", meaning I'd be looking to input between the `</p>` and `</body>` headers.

I've heard of many HTML parsers and API's such as **HTML Agility Pack**. Would any of those be a feasible option for doing as I would like to do?

Any suggestions are useful!

Comment: Why don't you use an XML processing library like: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/?

Comment: Because my HTML files are ridiculously small (essentially this format) where I'm looking at on a few headers. For larger HTML files I would would be using one.

Comment: Still I would use one since HTML and XML allow a lot of noise who is difficult to detect with string manipulation. For instance `<body bgcolor="black">` is valid as well. Using `StringBuilders` and readers would cause a lot of trouble to handle arguments, values,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) looks like it will do the job. However, if you just want to insert stuff before the closing `body` tag it might be a lot easier to do a simple regex to find the closing tag. You might even be able to just do:

```
htmlString.indexOf("</body>")
```

And add whatever you need before that.

Comment: I chose the Jsoup route. Definitely easier for further expansion. Great recommendation, thanks!